# unable to access $scope value in directive's controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a simple app, but some reason I am unable to access the $scope values in the directive's controller.

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngAnimate']);
```

**controller.js**

```
myApp.controller('controller1',['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.helloText = 'text';
}])
```

**directive.js**

```
myApp.directive('myPanel',function(){
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        scope : {
            someText : "="
        },
        templateUrl : 'someTemplate.html'
        controller : function($scope) {
            console.log($scope.someText);// this is undefined
        }
    };
});
```

**someTemplate.html**

```
<h1>This is the text {{someText}}</h1>
```

**main.html**

```
<div ng-controller="controller1">
    <my-panel someText="helloText"></my-Panel>
</div>
```

Need some pointers to understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should use normalized name `some-text` in html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your casing is off.

```
<my-panel some-text="helloText"></my-Panel>
```

You can read up on the normalization in [guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization)

Straight from the source

**Normalization**

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

**The normalization process is as follows:**

Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes. 
Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.